# Preventing direct access image url codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to prevent direct access images url in codeigniter 4

I tried make route

```php
$routes->get('/tester/(:any)', 'Tester::index/$1');
```

The file images is in folder public like: **public/tester/hero.jpg**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i restrict the image Folder using .htaccess in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28340198/how-can-i-restrict-the-image-folder-using-htaccess-in-codeigniter)